# How can I solve the old date displaying error in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I started developing apps using React Native not too long ago.
In the meantime, there was a situation in which the date data selected from the calendar had to be moved to another screen.
At first, I tried to move the date data by sharing data between screens, but the error continued.
But I tried another way to deliver the data well and built it.
The way I thought about it was to take 'async storage' and convert the date data into a string and save it.
This method was successful but had a fatal problem.

First, I found the following situation.
[image: This Gif is what happens when you click February 1st.]
When I first started the app and selected February 1st, the date was not displayed after the screen was moved.

Then I went back to the first screen and clicked February 2nd.

This will display the date on the screen.
But I chose February 2nd, but it says February 1st instead of February 2nd.

This indicates that the detail screen will display the previously selected date rather than the date selected now.

I don't know how to solve this problem.
This is something I've never encountered while programming.

This is my code

Home.js

```js
import React from "react";
import { SafeAreaProvider } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import { Calendar } from "react-native-calendars";
import { View, Alert } from "react-native";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

var dateString = "";

const savereturndate = async (value) => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem("selectdate", dateString);
  } catch (e) {
    Alert.alert("Error", e, [{ text: "OK", onPress: () => null }]);
  }
};

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  const markedDates = {
    "2023-02-01": { marked: true, dotColor: "red" },
  };
  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <View>
        <Calendar
          markedDates={markedDates}
          onDayPress={(day) => {
            for (var key in day) {
              //console.log("key:" + key + "/" + day[key])
              dateString = day[key];
            }
            savereturndate();
            navigation.push("Detail");
          }}
        />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

Detail.js

```js
import React from "react";
import { SafeAreaProvider } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import { View, Text, Alert } from "react-native";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

var returndatedetail = "";

const getreturndate = async () => {
  try {
    const hello = await AsyncStorage.getItem("selectdate");
    returndatedetail = hello.toString();
  } catch (e) {
    Alert.alert("Error", e, [{ text: "OK", onPress: () => null }]);
  }
};

function DetailScreen() {
  getreturndate();
  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <View>
        <Text>{returndatedetail}</Text>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
}

export default DetailScreen;
```

This is my development environment.
OS: macOS Monterey(12.6.3)
Development Program: Visual Studio Code (1.71.1)
Simulator: iPhone 14 (ios 16.2)
React native Version: 9.2.0

And I am using expo go to test it.

Can someone help me with this problem?
If so, help me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you're trying to do, but let me go through a few things that I founded in your code.

#### Screens

As I'm seeing here you have two basic Screens:

- Home: Defined by the Calendar in which navigates to the Detail Screens on pressing any of the dates.
- Detail: Defined by atm just a screen that shows the user some date.

#### Problem Fix Proposal

By looking into the definitions of Screens and understanding your problem, I don't think you need to store the currentDate into AsyncStorage. The navigation itself could handle that for you.

Try to do:

**Home.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { SafeAreaProvider } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import { Calendar } from "react-native-calendars";
import { View} from "react-native";

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  const markedDates = {
    "2023-02-01": { marked: true, dotColor: "red" },
  };
  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <View>
        <Calendar
          markedDates={markedDates}
          onDayPress={(day) => {
            navigation.navigate("Detail", { day });
          }}
        />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

**Detail.js**:

```
import React from "react";
import { SafeAreaProvider } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import { View, Text, Alert } from "react-native";


function DetailScreen({ route }) {
  const { day } = route.params;

  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <View>
        <Text>{day}</Text>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
}

export default DetailScreen;
```

Why not just do that? Passing the pressed `day` to the Detail Screen, where you can handle anything you want. Beyond that everytime the day changes the `navigation` will basically handle that for you, navigating to a new Screen in the stack or not (if it's already there).

Comment: Thanks, but even with this method, it shows the previously selected date, not the now selected date.